# Sorting a dataframe by a column with highest occuring Names on top

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Lets assume we have a dataframe df

```
    Name    Age
0   Mukul   22
1   Rohan   22
2   Mukul   21
3   Manoj   20
4   Kamal   21
5   Rohan   24
6   Robin   20
```

I am tring to sort the existing dataframe and rearrange it keep the highest number of occurence of Name on top

So the o/p I am getting is -

## use count() and sort()

`df = df.groupby(['Name'])['age'].count().reset_index(name='Count').sort_values(['Count'], ascending=True)`

```
    Name    Count
0   Kamal   1
1   Manoj   1
2   Robin   1
3   Mukul   2
4   Rohan   2
```

Rather my desired O/P I need is -

```
    Name    Age
0   Mukul   22
1   Mukul   21
2   Rohan   22
3   Rohan   24
4   Robin   20
5   Manoj   20
6   Kamal   21
```

The o/p should overwrite the same dataframe in format in which the highest number of occurence of a Name are on the top.

I really appreciate any help from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
import numpy as np

def freq_sorter(s):
    return -s.map(s.value_counts())

out = df.iloc[np.lexsort([df['Name'], freq_sorter(df['Name'])])]
```

Output:

```
    Name  Age
0  Mukul   22
2  Mukul   21
1  Rohan   22
5  Rohan   24
4  Kamal   21
3  Manoj   20
6  Robin   20
```

Or with a temporary column:

```
out = (
 df.assign(count=lambda d: d.groupby('Name').transform('count'))
   .sort_values(by=['count', 'Name'], ascending=[False, True],
                ignore_index=True))
   .drop(columns=['count'])
)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Age
0  Mukul   22
1  Mukul   21
2  Rohan   22
3  Rohan   24
4  Kamal   21
5  Manoj   20
6  Robin   20
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can convert the column to ordered category type then sort

```py
df['Name'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['Name'], ordered=True, categories=df['Name'].value_counts().index)
out = df.sort_values('Name')
```

```
print(out)

    Name  Age
0  Mukul   22
2  Mukul   21
1  Rohan   22
5  Rohan   24
3  Manoj   20
4  Kamal   21
6  Robin   20
```

Or if you prefer chained operation

```py
out = (df.assign(Name=pd.CategoricalIndex(df['Name'], ordered=True, categories=df['Name'].value_counts().index))
       .sort_values('Name', ignore_index=True)
       .astype({'Name': str})) # convert the column type back
```

```
print(out)

    Name  Age
0  Mukul   22
1  Mukul   21
2  Rohan   22
3  Rohan   24
4  Manoj   20
5  Kamal   21
6  Robin   20
```